# SQL to return distinct records with priority on first found item

Tags: postgresql

table:

```
 id | tag | pk
----+-----+----
  1 | 111 |  1
  2 | 111 |  2
  2 | 112 |  3
  3 | 111 |  4
  4 | 333 |  5
  4 | 334 |  6
  4 | 111 |  7
  5 | 335 |  8
... for 1,000,000 rows
```

Desired output

```
 id | tag | pk
----+-----+----
  1 | 111 |  1
  2 | 111 |  2
  3 | 111 |  4
  4 | 111 |  7
  5 | 335 |  8
... for limit of 500 rows
```

I want to return distinct id, but I want to first return the row where tag = 111 as the distinct; otherwise, first one found will do. I also want to limit the output to 500 rows.

I looked at unions, intersects... however, was unable to produce required results.

Comment: Will there only ever be one 111 for any one id, or can there be multiples, ex: (id, tag, pk)
(1,111,1)
(1,111,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` clause :

```
SELECT * FROM t;
┌────┬─────┬────┐
│ id │ tag │ pk │
├────┼─────┼────┤
│  1 │ 111 │  1 │
│  2 │ 111 │  2 │
│  2 │ 112 │  3 │
│  3 │ 111 │  4 │
│  4 │ 333 │  5 │
│  4 │ 334 │  6 │
│  4 │ 111 │  7 │
│  5 │ 335 │  8 │
└────┴─────┴────┘
(8 rows)
```

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM t 
ORDER BY id, (CASE tag WHEN 111 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
┌────┬─────┬────┐
│ id │ tag │ pk │
├────┼─────┼────┤
│  1 │ 111 │  1 │
│  2 │ 111 │  2 │
│  3 │ 111 │  4 │
│  4 │ 111 │  7 │
│  5 │ 335 │  8 │
└────┴─────┴────┘
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.